# i can't populate my table view in java fx

Tags: java

I can't seem to find a way to populate my table:(, if i look at them seperatly they sow to me im my Console, even if i add a manual object to my observebleList it work, it just don't add my data inported ....

```
This is my Controller:
package Interface;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.TextFieldTableCell;
public class ControllerForFinalPoint implements Initializable {
    String id ; 
    String x ; 
    String y ; 
    String z ;
    public void exitApplication(ActionEvent exitApplication) {
        Platform.exit();
    }
    public void intoarcere (String id, String x, String y, String z) {
        this.id = id;
        System.out.println(id);
        this.x = x;
        System.out.println(x);
        this.y = y;
        System.out.println(y);
        this.z = z;
        System.out.println(z);
    }

    @FXML
    private TableView<MyPointFinal> tableCoord2;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<MyPointFinal, String> Id;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<MyPointFinal, String> X;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<MyPointFinal, String> Y;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<MyPointFinal, String> Z;

    ObservableList<MyPointFinal> data = FXCollections.observableArrayList(
                    new MyPointFinal(id, x, y, z));

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {

        Id.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<MyPointFinal, String>("Id"));
        Id.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.forTableColumn());
        X.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<MyPointFinal, String>("X"));
        X.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.forTableColumn());
        Y.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<MyPointFinal, String>("Y"));
        Y.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.forTableColumn());
        Z.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<MyPointFinal, String>("Z"));
        Z.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.forTableColumn());
        tableCoord2.setItems(data);

    }

}
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TableView?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>

<VBox maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="500.0" prefWidth="700.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.60" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="Interface.ControllerForFinalPoint">
   <children>
      <TableView fx:id="tableCoord2" editable="true" prefHeight="558.0" prefWidth="600.0">
         <columns>
            <TableColumn fx:id="Id" prefWidth="75.0" text="Name" />
            <TableColumn fx:id="X" prefWidth="150.0" text="X" />
            <TableColumn fx:id="Y" prefWidth="150.0" text="Y" />
            <TableColumn fx:id="Z" prefWidth="150.0" text="Z" />
         </columns>
      </TableView>
      <AnchorPane prefHeight="59.0" prefWidth="700.0">
         <children>
            <Button layoutX="118.0" layoutY="34.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Save" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="17.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="325.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="325.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="17.0" />
         </children>
      </AnchorPane>
      <AnchorPane prefHeight="38.0" prefWidth="600.0" />
   </children>
</VBox>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the  problem is that methods aren't called in the order you think. First javafx creates the instance , and therefore initializing the field `ObservableList data` using the variables 'id', 'x', 'y', 'z'. After that javafx will call the`initialize()` method which is using the mentioned ObservableList. After that you are able to call `intoarcere()` which sets the fields used previously to build the ObservableList content.... (whoops).

So the actual MyPointFinal instance is there (as confirmed when you log its content), though nothing will be visible since every value is 'null'.

If you change the `intoarcere()` to the following you should see results.

```
public void intoarcere (String id, String x, String y, String z)
{
    this.data.add(new MyPointFinal(id, x, y, z));
}
```

Ps. currently you use variable names with both capital and lower case 'x', 'y' and 'z'. Not only are 'PascalCased' variable names against the general naming convention, it is also quit confusing (for others, but also for yourself after a while). Please try to rename them for your own sake.

Comment: tx , for the first one it was not that probleme.i find out that my data that was supose to go in to my list was null, i need to call the methode in the other direction or do somthing else, as for the "PS" thank you i will keep in mind.